# Как правильно: «сеть салонов оптики» или «сеть салонов оптик»? Почему? Какие правила мы при этом используем?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, единственное-множественное-число

Директор хочет везде писать «сеть салонов оптик», но я не могу объяснить, почему это словосочетание кажется мне неверным.

Answer (score 1):

Да, неверно, можно объяснить на похожих примерах:
*сеть салонов красот;

сеть магазинов одежд;

сеть магазинов для охот;

сеть магазинов техник*.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь:
2) а) Отрасль промышленности, занимающаяся изготовлением оптических приборов.  *Электромашиностроение и оптика - ведущие отрасли промышленности в Санкт-Петербурге.*
Не подходит.
б) Учреждение, торгующее такими инструментами, приспособлениями.
"Сеть салонов учреждений" не подходит.
в) Такие инструменты и приспособления бытового назначения (линзы, бинокли и т.п.).
Здесь собирательное (только единственное число).
3) *собир.* Приборы и инструменты, действие которых основано на законах отражения и преломления света.
Здесь собирательное (только единственное число).

Вывод: слово "оптика" во множественном числе может быть только в значении б).

Answer (score 0):

Слово это во мн. ч. как в родительном, так и в других падежах, иногда употребляется, и такие примеры есть: «*Выход за пределы собственно исторического взгляда и совмещение оптик философа и историка-практика*».

Не для вывески сети салонов, а для упоминания салонов ***оптики различного назначения*** в тексте, допускающем некий профессиональный подход, словосочетание можно признать корректным.

Comment: В тексте каком? Допускающ**е**м.

Comment: оk, оk, оk, оk, оk, оk